# Filling Regions (Blocks) of a Binary Matrix with Different Probabilities

Tags: matrix, list-manipulation, sparse-arrays

This is an extension of the following question:
[How to generate binary array whose elements with values 1 are randomly drawn](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/193418/how-to-generate-binary-array-whose-elements-with-values-1-are-randomly-drawn), where the most elegant answer was posted in the comments:

```
ArrayReshape[SparseArray[Transpose[{RandomSample[Range[400], 300]}] -> 1, {400}], {20, 20}]
```

The above snippet of code produces a 20x20 matrix whose elements contain 300 1's and 100 0's. I would like to extend this procedure by applying some specific rules. Primarily, I want to leave the diagonal empty and I want to be able to fill specific regions (blocks) on the matrix with different probabilities. For example, in the first 10 rows and 10 columns (upper left block) I would like to have 50 of 100 elements to be 1, while in the final 10 rows and 10 columns (bottom right block) I would like 30 of 100 elements to be 1. Is there a way to modify the above code to do this? My first guess is to generate each block separately and combine them, but I am unsure if that is the nicest way to go about it. Thanks!

Comment: Is this for generating networks? Take a look at `IGStochasticBlockModel` in [IGraph/M](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM)

Comment: @Szabolcs Hey! Yeah it is, I have just taken a look and this is right up my alley. Thank you so much for your suggestions :) 

I also took a look at your profile and saw that you are involved with a program for interfacing Mathematica and MATLAB - I was wondering if I could get in contact with you about it to ask a question or two? I was just having a problem with the interface between these two programs.

Comment: Yes, you can write me.